# How to Call Smart Contract Function After Migrations

Tags: solidity, truffle, javascript

In my `2_deploy_contracts.js` file, I can successfully migrate all my contracts using the command `truffle migrate`. My problem is that after migration, I want to call a function from contract **D** and pass it the address of contract **E**.

My **`2_deploy_contracts.js`** file looks like this (contract names replaced):

```
const A = artifacts.require("A");
const B = artifacts.require("B");
const C = artifacts.require("C");
const D = artifacts.require("D");
const E = artifacts.require("E");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(A);
  deployer.deploy(B);
  deployer.deploy(C);
  deployer.deploy(D)
    .then(function() {
      return deployer.deploy(E, D.address);
    })
    .then(function() {
      return D.methods.setEContractAddress(E.address); // This line
    });
};
```

I have looked at other similar questions on this site but none have helped so far. **How do I call the `setEContractAddress()` function from contract ***D*** after contract ***E*** is migrated?**

Thank you for your help and time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
const D = artifacts.require("D");
const E = artifacts.require("E");

module.exports = async (deployer) => {
  await deployer.deploy(D)  
  const d = await D.deployed();    
  await deployer.deploy(E, d.address);
  const e = await E.deployed();
  await d.setEContractAddress(e.address);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Javier, it works now! You only need to add an arrow to the code for it to compile properly, like this: `async (deployer) => {` :)